# How to pass many parametrs to make template in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mako

Like this I can pass 1 parametr: `print(mytemplate.render(ThisGuysName=SubjectName))`
How to pass 3 parametrs ThisGuysName, ThisGuysEmail, ThisGuysAge?

Comment: Can you call `render(ThisGuysName=SubjectName, ThisGuysEmail=blah, ThisGuysAge=blah)`?  (I've not used mako personally, so I don't know :) )

Comment: Can you publish your code?

Comment: Sorry - yes your code works. render(ThisGuysName=SubjectName, ThisGuysEmail=blah, ThisGuysAge=blah). Error was in another place.